Голосовой помощник лучше на C++ или Python?
Думаю писать голосового помощника для личных целей и не могу определиться с языком, C++ или Python?
Стоит ли запариваться и писать ГП на C++, если можно на питоне?
Или же разница в производительности не столь большая и можно использовать Python?
Если все же стоит C++, скиньте мне, пожалуйста, библиотеки, api, которые поддерживают распознавание русского языка.

Начните с Питона. Уверен что вы отыщите все нужные библиотеки для работы со звуком и нейросетями. Но даже если вы во что-то упрётесь (например доступ к звуку только через С++ АПИ), переключитесь на С++ почти без потери времени.

Такое наречие как "лучше" - несет в себе максимально не информативный смысл, попробуйсте меня понять, поэтому стоит опираться на другие, существенные факторы, такие как: производительность, скорость, объем и т.д.
Таким образом, именно те факторы, которые явно могут присутствовать в
разработке "голосового помощника".
Отвечая на ваш вопрос, с более правильной формулировкой, С++ или Python, на обеих языках возможна реализация. Все зависит от вашего имеющегося старта, будто-бы в C++ или Python.

стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам стали доступны комментарии к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос
